# print the backslash in the pdf document

Tags: symbols

I want to print the following path `D:\\hl_sv` in the PDF document but I am facing problem that the backslash are not being displayed. How can escape them to write them in the pdf document.

**tex code:**

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}   % 
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}  

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}

\item[1.] Currently, the parser parses PDF files in this path \textbf{D:\\hl\_sv} which needs to be changed to the saved timetable files path.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

with package `url`

```
 [ ... ] this path \path{D:\\hl\_sv}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without any packages, in case you are not writing these too many times in your document:
`D:\textbackslash\textbackslash hl\_sv`where `\textbackslash`is used for `\`and the underscore is produced with `\_`, this is due to underscore representing subscript normally in LaTeX.

Here is the full code with the edit listed above, I also edited your list, as `enumerate` automatically numbers it:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}   % 
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}  

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

\item Currently, the parser parses PDF files in this path \textbf{D:\textbackslash\textbackslash hl\_sv} which needs to be changed to the saved timetable files path. 
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]